# how to assign ajax response in two different textbox elements ?(different values in each textbox)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', "");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("sr_db", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM client_info WHERE name like '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


echo $row['address'];
echo $row['balance'];


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

i want to display the two echo line in two different textbox on my main page... 
i have also written ajax code lines and it also run.... but don't know how display values of both the echo line  in two different textbox

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("address").value="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("address").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_search_address.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: when you got the ajax response and post to particular text area, first check the value belong to 1 text area if it has make the overlay condition to fill other textarea with value....

Comment: sorry its my mistake, i have written two echo lines just two tell that what i want ....  actually in my current program one echo line   works properly .... all i want is how to display both the echo's in different textbox ...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider sending the response from PHP with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and parsing the response:
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhr-responsetype-json

Short of that, you can set a delimiter in PHP, and split with javascript.  Ex:

```
<?php
echo $row['address'] . "|" . $row['balance'];
?>
```

Javascript

```
values = xlmhttp.responseText.split("|");
document.getElementById("address").value=values[0];
document.getElementById("balance").value=values[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the response in json format. it work as an array when receive in ajax call, then the data can be parsed accordingly.

**In server**

```
echo json_encode(array('address' => $row['address'], 'balance' => $row['balance']));
```

**In ajax end**

```
$.ajax({
url: "php page url",

type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',

success: function(json) {
 $('.address').val(json.address);
 $('.balance').val(json.balance);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any another way ... just like to assign variables declared in php, into the ajax (javascript) code...

Comment: i mean to say that.... can we assign $row['address'] variable to a javascrit variable....

Comment: I dont know such rules, but it is the easiest way for me.Json is being used widely now a days and its easy to use i recomend to use json format.